# How to see one line returned value in debug mode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, return-value, visual-studio-debugging

In debug mode, I can see what returned from method by moving mouse pointer to "name" variable;

```
public string GetUserName(int id)
{
    string name = UserService.GetUserName(id);
    return name;
}
```

But I don't want to create a variable to just to see what inside it...

So what is the proper way to debug one line returned method like;

```
public string GetUserName(int id)
{
    return UserService.GetUserName(id);
}
```

*Notes

- I don't want to use F11 to get inside of GetUserName method.
- I don't want to use immediate window.

Comment: put this statement: `UserService.GetUserName(id)` in the `watch` window

Comment: VS2013 supports that now

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer but everytime ( in every methods like this ) I'll have to change watch window's properties. This is not the answer that I looked for.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio's newest version, 2013, supports it right out of the box. In earlier versions, there's not much to do than to create a dummy variable and test it.

You can copy the whole method `UserService.GetUserName(id)` to the watch window and it will give you a result. If the method is deterministic then the result in the watch window will be the same one as in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use QuickWatch, or add a Watch to the watch window.

Select the whole expression (without "return" of course), then right click to use either of the two above mentioned tools.

Cheers

Comment: That only works if the function has no side effects. Otherwise the side effects get executede multiple times.

Comment: I didn't know that "no side effect" was part of the original question, was it ?

Comment: No but i though it was worth mentioning that that is the issue with this technique